How are Airlines like WizzAir able to fly between Saudia and Italy
As stated in the title I'm looking to understand how an airline like WizzAir Malta can fly between Milan, Rome, and Vienna from Riyadh. Their AOC is from Malta, and the EU has no open skies agreement with Saudia. So how is this possible?

Don't know if they have separate AOC for Saudi operations, but at least some of their aircraft are in UAE registration (A6)


"Their AOC is from Malta"

Wizz Air Malta Limited has an operator licence from Maltese authority and an EASA AOC (air operator certificate), EASA.AOC.003, since Sept. 2022:

Wizz Air, Europe’s fastest growing and most sustainable airline, is pleased to announce that Wizz Air Malta has been granted an Air Operator’s Certificate (AOC) by the European Union Aviation Safety Agency (EASA) and an Operating Licence (OL) by the Malta Civil Aviation Directorate (CAD).

Malta is part of the European Union, Wizz Air can fly to Saudia like other EU operators, pursuant to a pre-existing Bilateral Air Services Agreement (BASA) replaced by an Air Services Agreement (ASA) after all BASA were overruled by the Court of Justice.
The EASA AOC is listed here.
